# How can I limit the file size of files searched by ag?

Tags: ag

I don't want [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to search files larger than 2Mio.

I can't find anything like a --file-size flag to the ag command, but is there any way to tell it that?

I'm getting lots of

```
ERR: Skipping foo.bar: pcre_exec() can't handle files larger than 2147483647 bytes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `zsh`, with any command, not just `ag`, you can do:

```
ag -- pattern **/*(.LM-3)
```

To look (recursively with `**/`) in regular files (`.`) that are 2 MiB `L`arge or smaller (whose `L`ength rounded up to an integer number of `M`ebibytes, is strictly less (`-`) than `3`).

That excludes hidden files, but in the case of `ag`, files that are matched by `.ignore` files and co are not excluded when they're passed literally.

In bash or other Korn-like shells, on GNU systems, you could always use a function or script that does:

```
ag_in_small_non_hidden_files() {
  xargs -r0a <(
    LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -type f -size -3M -print0
  ) ag "$@"
}
```

To do something equivalent (with the file list not sorted, but then again, `ag` by default doesn't sort the file list again, and you can always pipe the `find` output to `sort -z` if you want a sorted list).

Answer (score 1):

You could do a pre-scan for files 2GiB large and over and write them to `.ignore` in the directory structure you are searching.

e.g.

```
find . -size "+$(( 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 - 1 ))c" > .ignore
```

Caveats apply around files with tricky characters such as newline, wildcards, backslashes, quote marks, or trailing whitespace in their path.

For files strictly larger than 2MiB, with some `find` implementations including GNU `find`, you can use `find . -size +2M`, which matches on files whose size round up to an integer number of mebibytes is strictly greater than 2, so files of size 2097153 (rounded up to 3MiB) and over. Take care that `-size -2M` would report files 1MiB large or smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the refinement, I think the OP has confused the size it's complaining about, by my eye it's 2GiB not 2MiB

Comment: Yes, that or they want to search in smallish files regardless of the PCRE limit, it's hard to tell.